# Setting the value of VBox to a different FXML VBox?

Tags: javafx, load, fxml, vbox

You can do it with a BorderPane ie:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("contacts.fxml"));
    HBox root = loader.load();
    rootPane.setTop(root);
}
```

The VBox does not have a .set(node) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `VBox` (and with many other `Pane`s) you just modify the `children` `ObservableList` the way you would modify any other `List`.

E.g.

```
// add root as bottom-most child of rootPane
rootPane.getChildren().add(root);
```